# Correlation between groups and ranks over different samples with R

Tags: r, correlation, dna-sequence

I'm studying some scores on DNA for which each position has a score.
I would like to find a method to know whether some samples are more often likely to have a high score, not in general, but position per position.
Some positions are not defined on all samples, and some samples don't have score for a given position.

```
data.frame('pos'=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,5), 'sample'=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'), 'score'=c(1,10,5,20,40,10,0.1,5,4))
```

I'd like to know using a spearman correlation (I'm looking for rankings as there is no real biological reasons to compare position 1 and 2 for instance) whether some samples are more likely to have the "top" scoring values.
My difficulty is that I have actually two qualitative values : the sample ID and the position and only one quantitative. I don't manage to indicate to R that I want somehow to group the data by position and then have a ranking on each position to study the correlation of rankings.

Finally I'd like to have a spearman correlation score assessing in that dataset that sample B is the top-scorer on most of the positions.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: So you are interested, for example, whether sample A has a higher score in position one compared to B, C. For given data example you are going to examine just three numbers.

Comment: Hi, yes you're right, and I found a way to do it position by position, but I'd like to know if given all the positions (here 4 in total), sample X is likely to have the highest score each time. Those score are actually "hotspots" and I'd like to know if the sample who has the highest score in one hotspot position is likely to have the highest (or one of the highest) on the other positions as well

Comment: IMHO That seems to be very different question than what can Spearman corr answer. Spearman is used when you cannot give a quantitative evaluation for the observation (he is 103cm tall), but you can still order them (he is better than others).  You can rank the scores, and then ask whether scores on positon 1, 2 are correlated. Is that what are you trying to do?

Comment: Did you mean to have the last value of `pos` be 5? ISTM it should be 3.

Comment: Hi, no the value is 5, I have some positions defined for some samples which are not defined in other samples and some positions don't have all the samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this points in the a helpful direction.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame('pos'=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), # Using 3 as the last position
'sample'=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'), 
'score'=c(1,10,5,20,40,10,0.1,5,4))

# Compute rank of each sample within each position
ranked = df %>% group_by(pos) %>% 
  mutate(rank=rank(score, ties.method='min')) %>% 
  ungroup()

# B seems to consistently score higher
ggplot(ranked, aes(pos, rank, color=sample)) +
  geom_point(size=5)
```

[image]

```r
# Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test of the null hypothesis that the rankings
# are from the same distribution for all samples.
kruskal.test(ranked$rank, ranked$sample)
#> 
#>  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 
#> data:  ranked$rank and ranked$sample
#> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 8, df = 2, p-value = 0.01832

# Pairwise Wilcoxon test for B vs C
df %>% filter(sample!='A') %>% 
  group_by(pos) %>% 
  mutate(rank=rank(score, ties.method='min')) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols='pos', names_from='sample', values_from='rank') %>% 
  {wilcox.test(.$B, .$C, paired=TRUE)}
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(.$B, .$C, paired = TRUE): cannot compute exact p-
#> value with ties
#> 
#>  Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  .$B and .$C
#> V = 6, p-value = 0.1489
#> alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

If the scores are all drawn from the same distribution, I think you could do these same tests on the scores directly, without ranking.

<sup>Created on 2020-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out this morning, and the ranking seems to give me a good indication. Although I'm not fully satisfied with my results. I have 50+ different samples, and the ggplot although very elegant, is impractical in this context.
The Kruskal test helped, and give me a significant p-value, which is interesting. However I'm doubtful in how to interpret this possible result. 
Isn't there any 'standard' procedure to rank samples in different positions? 
best,

Comment: I'm at the limit of what I know, sorry. The significant p-value in the Kruskal-Wallis test suggests you can reject the null hypothesis that the three rankings are drawn from the same distribution.